# Artwork recognizer - Xcode CoreML .mlmodel inaccurate

Tags: iphone, xcode, machine-learning, coreml, mlmodel

I'm trying to edit Apple Flower recogniser example for recognising an artwork/paintings. It's working actually very well. Every time I point the camera to the artwork I trained before, it's always accurate. Problem is, it's showing > 98% confidence when I'm pointing to my table for example... Or almost anywhere where I point (not on artwork) it shows to match.

Apple example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/training_a_create_ml_model_to_classify_flowers

What and I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. You can only use a machine learning model on the same types of inputs that it has been trained on.

If you want the model to say, "Not an artwork" when you point it at a table (or at anything else), it must be specifically trained for this.

Comment: wow, that's crazy but ok, good to know. Can you do that also in Xcode Image Classifier?

Comment: Not crazy at all. This is how image classifiers work (as well as pretty much any other ML model). The downside of creating a "none of the above" category is that this needs to have many more images of a much wider variety than the other classes, which may give you issues with imbalanced results etc. I don't think Create ML (which I think you're referring to) can handle class imbalances, but give it a try. :-)